# Values are not getting passed

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have 2 classes class 1: I3CHostInterface.cs and class 2: AnalyzerViewModel.cs
here values from I3CHostInterface.cs are not passing to AnalyzerViewModel.cs. please help me find a solution for this. I am new user, execuse me for any insufficient explanation. I3CHostInterface has the method GetDeviceList. the values from this method need to be passed to the AnalyzerViewModel class(3rd Line)

AnalyzerViewModel.cs:
 `var traceDevice = new TraceConfigurations(); traceDevice.NodeList = new List<NodeStructure>(); traceDevice.NodeList.AddRange(HostInterface.GetDeviceList(eNodeType.Master));`

I3CHostInterface: HostInterface is the instance created for this class:

`public static HostInterface _instance;`

```
 `public static NodeStructure[] GetDeviceList(eNodeType nodeType)
    {
        return DeviceConfiguration.GetNodeList(nodeType);
    }`
```

Comment: Hi falcon, its hard to tell what you are asking, and the formatting is difficult to understand.  See how to format posts using markdown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What does DeviceConfiguration.GetNodeList(nodeType) returns? What does "values are not getting passed" means? Give an example.

Comment: it returns the configuration values of master and slave. so those master and slave configurations need to be passed to AnalyzerViewModel class for displaying it in .xml file

Comment: It probably is not returning what you think. You should attach a debugger and see, step by step, what it is doing. An alternative is, in HostInterface, do something like var nodes = DeviceConfiguration.GetNodeList(nodeType); Console.WriteLine(nodes.Length);

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a new list and then add the array items to it.

You can use the toList() method, to cast your array to a list.
Like this:

```
var traceDevice = new TraceConfigurations(); 
traceDevice.NodeList = HostInterface.GetDeviceList(eNodeType.Master).ToList();
```